# How should I do this animation or how should I aproach this dilemma?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, procedure

So, I have a cube and I want to make a game where the cube jumps from a pylon to another and now I am at the point where I want to make the pylon fall if the cube stays on it more than a given amount of time.

I don't want to use physics or rigid body, I am using just `transform.position` and `Raycast` to click on the next pylon I want the cube to jump, I want to use animations, so if the cub stays more than a given amount of time on the current pylon, that pylon will fall taking the cube with it.

The problem is that I don't know what to do, where to begin; regarding animations in unity I only know how to do Animation Clips.

I would learn to do other things but I actually have no ideea how to approach this problem, what technique should I use to get the desired outcome, and how?

Comment: Considering your pylon needs to fall down, you could make a counter for 3 seconds, followed by the pylon changing its `transfrom.position.y` to 0. To achieve an 'animation' effect, you could use the `Vector3.Lerp` function to move the pylon. Although I would differently recommend using `RigidBody` since it would make everything much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to detect if the cube is on the pylon.
2. If it is, then you need to start a timer.
3. If the timer reaches 0 then the pylon falls.

You can use [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) to Detect if the cube has collided with (landed on) the pylon:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    // Check if it is the cube that has collided.
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")  // Make sure to assign the Player Tag to the cube
    {
        // Start countdown timer.
    }
}
```

You could start a countdown timer using a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). 
You will need to add `using System.Collections;` at the top of your class.

Call your coroutine using `StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());`

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    // Wait for 3 seconds.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    // Make the pylon fall now.
}
```

This code will cause the game to wait for 3 seconds before doing something. How you make the pylon fall is up to you, you could use a RigidBody and set [isKinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) from true to false as an example, but since you have said you don't want to use physics, you could translate the pylon downwards using `Transform.position`.

This should get you started.